# Why does Python slow to a crawl in this code?

Tags: python

So I'm doing an Euler Project problem trying to incorporate the Sieve of Eratosthenes to find the largest prime factor of a number, however when I try to fill my initial hashtable it slows to a crawl and eats up gigs worth of RAM and takes over my CPU. Can anyone explain why? I realize the code itself is probably subpar

```py
allNums = {}
maxNum=600851475143
maxFactor=0

#fill dictionary, slows to a crawl here
for x in xrange(2,maxNum+1):
    allNums[x]=True

#sieve of Erastosthenes 
for x in xrange(2,len(allNums)):
    y=x
    if allNums[x]:
        y **= 2
        while y<=maxNum:
            if allNums[y]:
                allNums.pop(y)
            y+=x

#largest prime factor
for x in allNums:
    if maxNum%x==0 and x>maxFactor:
        maxFactor=x

print x
```

Comment: second for loop has a loop inside, so it can't be O(N) and therefore, the script shouldn't be O(3N)

Comment: That is... a very big number. I can see why it takes a long time to run.

Comment: Okay that's what i thought, i honestly had no idea how long it would take to compute a number that big

Comment: First loop builds a dict with 600 billion entries. The first loop  won't ever finish since you don't have enough memory.

Comment: Why are you filling the dictionary beforehand? You're essentially negating any benefits of using a hash/map by completely filling that hash/map.

Comment: I was attempting to use the Sieve of Erastosthenes to solve the problem with requires a data structure containing all the numbers from 2 to the number inputted.

Comment: Well, everyone can get a crazy idea in the beginning, it's not the reason to downvote the question. We all had our learning moments :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you allocate a huge list (maxNum*4 bytes, right)? Even if it is a dictionary and you can search there with log(N) complexity, it is still going to take significant time (and, more importantly, memory). Such a huge list might not even fit into your RAM, therefore your OS would have to imitate the extra memory (which would mean even longer access time to just read that data).

By the way, this is how your problem can be done (not very effective - takes a couple of seconds on my machine :) - but with the idea similar to Eratosphene sieve, except for a small optimization, namely not to continue if `x*x > maxNum`.

```
maxNum=600851475143

maxFactor=0

x = 1
while True:
    (quotient, remainder) = divmod(maxNum, x)
    if x>quotient:
        break
    if remainder==0:
        maxFactor=x
    x +=1

print maxNum, maxFactor
```

Comment: Worse that that, it's a dict with that many entries, Also, creating the 600 billion integer objects. So. about 80*600 gigabytes?

Comment: that seems like a stress-test for python, actually I am impressed that it worked at all :)

Comment: You don't have that much disk, so the OS can't help